# Creating trusted certificate chain

Tags: openssl

I have 4 certificatesin chain `rootCA.crt->A.crt->partner.crt->sm.crt` created with commands:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 356 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=www.aaa.com /C=US/L=San Fransisco" -keyout rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt

openssl genrsa -out A.key 2048
openssl req -new -key A.key -out A.csr -config csr.conf
openssl x509 -req -in A.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out A.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile cert.conf

openssl genrsa -out partner.key 2048
openssl req -new -key partner.key -out partner.csr -config csr_partner.conf
openssl x509 -req -in partner.csr -CA A.crt -CAkey A.key -CAcreateserial -out partner.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile cert_partner.conf

openssl x509 -req -in sm.csr -CA partner.crt -CAkey partner.key -CAcreateserial -out sm.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile cert_sm.conf
```

I would like to check if these certificates are trusted:

```
openssl verify -CAfile rootCA.crt -untrusted A.crt partner.crt sm.crt
```

Got errors:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error partner.crt: verification failed

error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error sm.crt: verification failed
```

Why these certificates are not trusted and how to fix that?

Comment: This isn't programming or development but (1) `partner.crt` _should_ work, given its name from the config differs from `A`, IF the extensions in `A.crt` are correct for a CA; are they? (2) even then `sm.crt` wouldn't work because (again given unique names) it isn't issued by `rootCA` or `A` (the checks of `partner.crt` and `sm.crt` are independent and separate; the latter doesn't use the former) (PS: did you really want to make the root validity 9 days shorter?)

Comment: According to my understanding roo validity is 365 days. How do you see it is 9 days?

Comment: Your first command, the one that creates rootCA.crt (and rootCA.key), has `-days 356`. 356=365-9.